# If I restart application pool, would the client browsers refer to my updated javascript or css files?

Tags: javascript, iis, browser-cache

If I forget to maintain versioning in js/css files i.e. script.js?v=1.0.1, and somehow I want to make sure that end users should refer to the updated version of the js/css, what is the best way to do that?

If I restart application pool in IIS, will it force end users to refer to the updated version of js/css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS cache lies in the server while browser cache lies in the client.
IISReset will clear the IIS cache but it won't do anything with local caches in client(browser).

Usually the caching issue is normally due to browsing cache , but sometime the culprit may be IIS caching . I would recommend Application pool Recycle instead of IIS restart.

Comment: will that make end users refer to my current js/css versions?

My question is: If I restart application pool, would the client browsers refer to my updated javascript or css files?

Comment: If the caching issue you face is due to browser cache , it will not update to latest version .For that you will have to clear browser cache or change css or js file names . If the caching issue is due to IIS Caching , restarting / or recycling app pool will solve the issue.